# ERROR - Unknown or duplicate parameter: WSGIPath

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, fastapi

I am finding issue with my WSGIPath in my fastapi elasticbeanstalk with Docker deployment.
When I deploy directly to EB it doesn't give any kind of error, only when I do it via Docker.

Can anyone add some light to this please

error

```
2022-10-27 17:48:59    ERROR   "option_settings" in one of the configuration files failed validation. More details to follow.
2022-10-27 17:48:59    ERROR   Unknown or duplicate parameter: WSGIPath
2022-10-27 17:49:00    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.`
```

.ebextensions

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    PYTHONPATH: "/var/app/current:$PYTHONPATH"
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: "server:app"

container_commands:
  01_initdb:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 database.py"
    leader_only: true`
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /code

COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt

ADD server.py /code/
ADD esquemas.py /code/
ADD database.py /code/
ADD pergunta.py /code/
ADD models.py /code/
ADD env /code/
ADD Procfile /code/

EXPOSE 80

COPY ./server.py /code/

CMD ["uvicorn", "server:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

I tried not including **.ebextensions**, I tried using **docker-compose.yml** and it didn't work either.

Comment: Your `WSGIPath` setting seems to be wrong. Looking at [this tutorial[(https://testdriven.io/blog/fastapi-elastic-beanstalk/), you should probably set it as `WSGIPath: server:app` (assuming you named your FastAPI application `app`, it's impossible to know without seeing the code). Then, make sure your `Procfile` launches `gunicorn` (as in the tutorial).

Comment: I ended up copying the `WSGIPath` that I was testing but was initially `"server:app"` (I'll edit the post), and still got the error `Unknown or duplicate parameter: WSGIPath` when using `Dockerfile`